# How to set a minimum timeout for curl(like libcurl 7.29) in PHP7

Tags: curl, timeout, libcurl, php-7

To guarantee the development environment can respond successfully, I would like to set a minimum timeout value for the curl response to return, like 300ms, `even when the timeout is set to 50ms` in the code to be deployed to production environment.

1. Is there a way to make this work?
2. Or are there any other alternatives to realize this? I just want the
   dev not to time-out due to the low performance of the test/dev machine.

**Environment:**

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
$ curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl only has a timeout, there's no "minimum" or "maximum" timeout. If you set a timeout to curl, that is what goes.

Technically speaking, there's both a connect timeout that only affects the "connection phase" and there's a global timeout that goes for the entire transfer, but you can only set either to a value or not set it.

If a timeout is set in code somewhere that uses curl or libcurl, there's no way for anyone on the outside to forcibly change that timeout to a higher value, using standard curl mechanisms.